# Good sources for Mishkan and Beis Hamikdash study

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, beis-hamikdash, mishkan-tabernacle

Anyone aware of any website, book, or video that you consider a really good resource for  Mishkan and Beis Hamikdash study? It would optimally include diagrams, video animations, and other interactive stuff. And why do you recommend it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I enjoy my copy of *[Carta’s Illustrated Encyclopedia of the Holy Temple in Jerusalem](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9652205303)*. It does a great job of helping the reader picture the architecture of the Mishkan and Beit Hamikdash and the service in them. I frequently refer to it for illustration when discussing these topics.

I also have enjoyed the novels I've read from the "Naftali in the Mikdash" series by [Yaakov Meir Strauss](http://www.feldheim.com/authors/strauss-yaakov-meir.html). They try to give you a sense of what it was like to live in Israel when the Beit Hamikdash stood. Sometimes, the Halachic exposition is a bit forced, but if you don't mind the fact that you're learning the Halachot as you go a long, it's an enjoyable educational experience.

Comment: I ABSOLUTELY LOVE THE STRAUSS BOOKS

Answer (score 2):

moshiach.com has an [interactive tour of the Beis Hamikdash](http://moshiach.com/temple/tour/).

Answer (score -1):

One  resource Here even though he seems to get the Keilim wrong:

http://thedeserttabernacle.blogspot.com/

Comment: Not a good resource; the runner of the blog is a heretic according to Rabbinic Judaism.