# Laughing in this world

Tags: halacha, simchah-joy-happiness

The Shulhan Aruch (Orah Haim 560:5) states

> אסור לאדם שימלא פיו שחוק בעולם הזה.‏
>
> It is forbidden to a person that he fill his mouth with laughter in this world.

I don't think I've ever met a person that doesn't laugh. Why don't most people follow this Halacha (i.e. what do they rely on)?

Comment: also says not to play music except for mitzva. but Rav Sheinberg zt'l permits it since people in our times would get depressed

Comment: "zt'l permits" :)

Comment: @DoubleAA "_Rashi_ says" and "the _Rambam_ holds" are very common phrases.

Comment: kohelet : a time to cry and a time to laugh

Comment: There is a Talmudic expression,[51] "His mouth did not cease laughing all day." Now we cannot accuse the Talmudic sages of laughing out loud (G-d forbid), for the sages explicitly ruled that "It is forbidden to fill one's mouth with laughter in this world."[52] Therefore, the sages' laughter must have consisted of no more than a dimpling of the cheeks. http://www.sichosinenglish.org/books/making-chassidim/09.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't ban laughter outright, only "to fill his mouth with laughter". *Mishna B'rura* clarifies it's speaking of "supernumerary joy". I claim that most people nowadays do follow this *halacha*.

Comment: You think most people follow this halacha on purpose or because they never come across such laughter?

Comment: @DoubleAA The latter.

Comment: You're saying nobody ever gets a crazy laugh in?

Comment: @HachamGabriel I said most people follow the _halacha_. Most people follow the _halacha_ banning theft, too. That doesn't mean nobody ever steals.

Comment: I've think I've seen different Heterim as well FTR.

Answer (score 1):

Most Rishonim e.g. Talmid Rabbeinu Yonah on the Rif to Berachos understand 'schok' to be pretty much synonymous with joy. This would be very limiting.
Rambam's view on the topic is discussed as he doesnt clearly cite this ruling.
The Menoras Hamaor (Kadmon) of Ri Alnakawa implies that the whole law is a "midas chassidus" a pious but not mandatory practice.
R. Nota Greenblatt, the noted posek of the South told me bluntly that "we dont hold of that Shulchan Aruch" he used the prevalent behavior of people as an indicator that we dont hold of it.  THus emphasizing the primacy of psak through minhag over "official halacha." Rather, he seemed to prefer reverse engineering the halacha through the minhag (to a degree).

Answer (score 0):

Presumably based on the verse "אז ימלא שחוק פינו ולשוננו רינה" - only then (when Hashem returns Israel to the Land and the goyim realize that "Hashem has done great things for them") can our mouths really be *filled* with laughter.

Comment: So it is impossible to violate the issur?

Comment: Maybe it's this: a person violates the issur when he or she feels a full or a complete joy that is undiminished by the knowledge of the exile. Even when our joy is at its greatest, we have to be aware that it is not truly full until the geulah.

Comment: Just the opposite! The Sefarim use this Pasuk to prove that only then we are **allowed** to laugh.