# Is Moshiach Going to last forever?

Tags: time, messiah

Is Moshiach Going to last forever?

When Moshiach comes are we going to have it for eternity?

If there are different opinions the please state them all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everyone agrees that Olam Haba is the ultimate reward and will last forever. There is a difference of opinion what olam haba is.

The Rambam says it's Gan Eden, which is spiritual. Moshiach will be temporary, and afterwards the physical world will cease and we'll have Gan Eden.

The Ramban says that olam haba is Moshiach, and it will last forever in this physical world.

Kabbalah (and Chassidus) follows the opinion of the Ramban.

Source: Derech Mitzvosecha, Tzitzis

Comment: Where does the Rambam say Gan Eden is Olam Haba?  In intro to Chelek, he says Gan Eden is a place on Earth with nice trees and rivers and special herbal remedies.

Answer (score 2):

The third Beish Hamikdash will be the last one and it will be eternal because Hashem will build himself. And when Moshiach comes the whole world will be Eretz Yisroel and now what is Ertez Yisroel will be Yerushalayim. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Sources would help

Comment: Why does Hashem building it himself imply it will be eternal?

Comment: Because nothing that he creates can be destroyed

Answer (score 2):

According to the Rambam, Moshiach will not last forever.

I am not sure if you mean the individual or the time period, but both are temporary.

In intro to Chelek, the Rambam writes that the King Moshiach will live a long life, and he will die and be succeeded by his progeny.  The age of tranquility that Moshiach will usher in will last longer than Moshiach himself, but even that will end and eventually the souls will all enter a purely spiritual realm and leave behind this world, which the age of Moshiach is a part of.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Ramchal, the Mashiach won't last forever. The Mashiach will come sometime before the year 6000. The purpose of the moshiach is to get Am Yisrael back into the proper form (e.g. dwelling in Eretz Yisrael, according to their tribes and ancestral heritage, able to study torah free of interference from the nations).

Then, in the year 6000, the world will be destroyed, and sit fallow for 1000 years. After that the world will be rebuilt in another form that we can't even fathom, which will begin a period called Olam Haba, where we receive the true reward for the mitzvot we did in Olam Hazeh. Olam Haba lasts forever.

Note well: according to the Ramchal, Olam Haba is a different stage in the cycle of the world, which comes after the time of the Mashiach.

(To see this for yourself, read Ma'amar HaIkarim, and Derech Hashem.)

Comment: Whic Rebbe states this?

Comment: will he still be moshiah resurected though after the "1000" years (whatever that means if time/space will be destroyed)

Comment: I don't really understand either of your questions.

Comment: so moshiach will be lasting forever during the periods when human beings will be in existence?, i.e. not including the "break" periods.

Comment: @ray: Olam Haba is the place where we will recieve the ultimate reward. According to the Ramchal, God has not granted us sufficient closeness to him to even comprehend what that reward will be like, or to understand the way in which that world will be organized. So I think it's fair to say that no, the moshiach will not last forever. It's the stepping stone to something greater, presumably a world where we can interact with God without intermediaries.